# Reading data that is being sent to localhost by another application

Tags: python, python-3.x

An application I'm using has the option to enable an API that sends some data when certain events occur to a URL. I configured it to send the data to  http://localhost:666/simple/ and used a short program (written by someone else in C#) that takes the data and dumps them to a text file. The author said that you need to run the .exe as administrator to be able to listen to http events and it did indeed work.

I'm trying to achieve the same using python. I took [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) short example from the requests library and adapted it to the following:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:666/simple/'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    print(line)
```

I launched command prompt with administrator privileges, but when I try to run this script I get the following error: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Since the other program is working correctly, I am assuming I am doing something wrong in my code and I'm looking for some help to fix it or an alternative to try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests are used for, well, making requests from a server, not for being a server. 
 You may want to look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/http.server.html)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Just to clarify, I just want to read data that is being sent by another application on my computer every time I execute certain actions within that application. Can http.server do that?

Comment: Yes, the other application is going to be trying to send data to a server on your computer, so you need to run a server of some sort.  Given the URL you use it's likely that an http server would be just the thing.

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot. I haven't been able to quite make it work as I wish yet, but I should be able to figure the rest out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

use [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) to listen data on concrete port